# React-Native-Navigation v2 - Avatar/Image/Component as bottomTab Icon

Tags: react-native-navigation-v2

I was curious if it is possible to use a component in place of the icon property in bottomtab of react-native-navigation-v2.

Example:

```
bottomTab: {
    text: 'Profile',
    icon: <Image  source={{uri: 'myUrlHere'}} style={styles.someStyle}/>,
    textColor: '#fff',
}
```

Example2 using react-native-elements Avatar component:

```
bottomTab: {
    text: 'Profile',
    icon: <Avatar rounded source={{uri: 'myUrlHere'}}/>,
    textColor: '#fff',
}
```

If this has been posted before, forgive me, I just could not find it in my searches.